# text Scrolling inside movieclip in Flash 8

Tags: flash

I'm trying to show text on mouseover of a movieclip.

mc1.onRollOver = function()
{
    mc1.gotoAndStop(2);
    stop();
}
mc1.onRollOut = function()
{
    mc1.gotoAndPlay(1);
    play();
}

on frame 2 inside movieclip I've created a textbox which is dynamic & multiline and add a scrollbar. but its not working.

Outside the movieclip its working but inside movieclip its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You may put a textbox into separate layer and hold it in both frames of the mc1 (do not make a keyframe on the textbox layer in the 2nd frame), and then control textbox visibility with _visible property.

Your code might look like this:

```
mc1.yourTextBoxInstanceName._visible=false;
mc1.onRollOver = function() {mc1.yourTextBoxInstanceName._visible=true; mc1.gotoAndStop(2); stop(); } 
mc1.onRollOut = function() {mc1.yourTextBoxInstanceName._visible=false; mc1.gotoAndPlay(1); play();}
```